# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error Only on a Single Route, Only When Deployed to GAE

Tags: reactjs, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, long-polling

I'm using google app engine to host both my frontend and my api backend. I'm getting the following errors when I'm polling the "slicingdone" route on my backend:

> bootstrap e65cef5bb029055e1719:2 GET
>   https://playloopsbackend-217106.appspot.com/playloops/slicingdone 502
>   send @ bootstrap e65cef5bb029055e1719:2
>
> /videotogifs:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://playloopsbackend-217106.appspot.com/playloops/slicingdone'
>   from origin 'https://playloopsfrontend.appspot.com' has been blocked
>   by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
>   the requested resource.

I poll the slicingdone function to figure out when trimming of a video on my backend is finished. It works locally but is presenting the above errors when deployed to gcloud.

slicingdone function on my backend looks like this(Express):

```
  slicingdone(req, res, next) {
if(slicingIsDone == true){
  res.status(200).send('true');
  slicingIsDone = false;
}else{
  res.status(200).send('false');
}
```

}

*Every other route on my backend works fine even when deployed. I have similar functions on the backend that manipulate videos using ffmpeg in different ways. I have whitelisted my frontend url on my backend, so I'm not sure why I'm getting these CORs errors. I store the video results in google cloud storage--perhaps I need to add my backend url to google cloud CORS whitelist?

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!